# Add two panels in jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I create a `JFrame` and I want two panels one above and one below dividing the `JFrame` in two.

InicioAdministrador is the `JFrame`

InicioPartida is the `JPanel`

I created everything with visual editor.

Answer (score 1):

You will need one of the many possible choices of Layout managers.
I could explain it here, but I think http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html will do a better job at it ;)

Answer (score 1):

For this you might use a single column `GridLayout`.  It will divide the space equally between components.

See also:

- [Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

  - [How to Use GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)
- The [Nested Layout Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) (for ideas about how to *combine* layouts to create the required layout).

[image]